# How to determinate a theme-elements hook

Tags: php, woocommerce, themes, hook, hook-woocommerce

So I tried replacing a "sale badge" from my WooCommerce theme

[image]

On this image you can see what I wanted to change.

Actually I'am really close to the solution I guess.

With this code:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', function ( $html, $post, $product ) {
    $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
    $sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();

    if ( ! empty( $regular_price ) && ! empty( $sale_price ) && $regular_price > $sale_price ) {
    $saved_price = wc_price( $regular_price - $sale_price );
    $html = '<span class="sale-item product-label type-bubble">' . esc_html__( 'Du sparst', 'woocommerce' ) . '  ' . $saved_price  . '</span>';
    return $html;
}
}, 10, 3 );
```

I was able to get this result (I already removed one of the 2xcurrency showing up):

[image]

The only issue now... I need to find out the correct hook for the original "sales badge". I have searched through a lot of files but wasnt able to find anything. Thats why I wonder if there is a smarter way for finding a hook.

With kind regards
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`woocommerce_sale_flash()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/sale-flash.php#L27) to modify sale badge.

Try out this code(not tested):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', function ($html, $post, $product) {
    $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
    $sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();

    if (!empty($regular_price) && !empty($sale_price) && $regular_price > $sale_price) {
        $saved_price = wc_price($regular_price - $sale_price);
        $html = '<span class="sale-item product-label type-bubble">' . esc_html__('Du sparst', 'woocommerce') . '  ' . $saved_price  . '</span>';
        return $html;
    }
}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :) Sadly that one will place it right above the product title (as you can see it on the screenshot I posted above.)

Comment: then you have to check in your theme for any modification in woocommerce templates files.